# How to override bootstrap panel-heading color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know there are many questions like mine. However none of them are working. I have this html file:

```
<div class="container col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="panel-group">
     <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading-custom panel-heading ">Username</div>
        <div class="panel-body panel-info">{{ main.username }}</div>

     </div>
</div>
```

and this css file:

```
.panel-default > .panel-heading-custom {
    color: #333;
    background: black;
    border-color: #ddd;
 }
```

i've tried many options:

`.panel-heading`
`.panel-default > .panel-heading`
`.panel-default.panel-heading`
`.panel.panel-heading`

And a couple more. I know you can us !important, but I don't think that's the right way to do it. Could you please help me with that?

This is what appears on my browser:

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a fiddle replicating your problem

Comment: I haven't really used JSFiddle but i'll give it a try

Comment: I tried to add your code in this pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mRQKWp ...but could not find any problem with your code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dietic/u91zaguL/3/
Somehow it works in JSFiddle but it doesn't work when I use localhost.

Comment: I guess someother styles are overriding your styles ..check on it other wise your code is perfectly fine,if overrding ,you have to use !important

Comment: Check out the addition I made to my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your styles are being overridden. You can make sure that your styles to be not overridden either by

1. using !important
2. you can write the style as to have highest specificity
3. if there are two/more styles defined for a particular class or a selector, what ever comes last will come to effect

check this snippet

```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
.panel-default>.panel-heading-custom {
    color: #333;
    background: black;
    border-color: #ddd;
 }
</style>

<div class="container col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="panel-group">
     <div class="panel panel-default">

        <div class="panel-heading-custom panel-heading heading ">Username</div>
        <div class="panel-body panel-info">{{ main.username }}</div>

     </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Somehow it works in my browser now... hahaha Thanks!